# ConTeXt: Place rules above and below floating figure

Tags: floats, context, rules

I'm experimenting to place a rule above and below a floating figure to achieve the following design. But to no avail.

I've tried to place a `\blackrule` before and after the `\placefigure`. But that's obviously not gonna work since the float floats around the document without taking the rule with it.

[image: Mock up]

**EDIT:**

I tried the following code, which doesn't quite do the trick. I need the rule above the caption.

`\startplacefigure
    \blackrule[width=\textwidth,height=.8pt,color=red]
    \externalfigure[kitten.jpg][width=\textwidth]
    \blackrule[width=\textwidth,height=.8pt,color=red]
\stopplacefigure`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please provide some example code that shows the problem and/or your attempts so far?

Comment: Try `\startplacefigure\blackrule\externalfigure [kitten]\blackrule\stopplacefigure`. Then you'd just need to adjust captioning.

Comment: @TeXnician But then how do I get the caption beneath the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no in-built option for this, but it is relatively straight forward to implement using the core commands:

```
\def\floatbackrule{\blackrule[width=\textwidth,height=.8pt,color=red]}

\unprotect
\installfloatboxbuilder {topframed}    \strc_floats_build_box_top_framed
\installfloatboxbuilder {bottomframed} \strc_floats_build_box_bottom_framed

\def\strc_floats_build_box_top_framed
    {\floatbackrule
     \strc_floats_build_box_top
     \floatbackrule}

\def\strc_floats_build_box_bottom_framed
    {\floatbackrule
     \strc_floats_build_box_bottom
     \floatbackrule}

\protect
```

Here is an example:

```
\setupcaption
  [
    location=topframed,
  ]

\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}] 

\starttext 

\section{A figure with rules} 

\input knuth

\startplacefigure[title={A dutch cow}, location=top]
  \externalfigure[cow]
\stopplacefigure

\dorecurse{4}{\input knuth \endgraf}

\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

**Addendum**: This simple method fails with longer captions and does not work with the `align` option. The reason is that an internal macro `\strc_floats_prepare_page_caption` does some corrections with the `location` parameter is `top` or `bottom`. These corrections don't take place when `location` is set to `topframed`. To fix this, we need to patch `\strc_floats_prepare_page_caption' as follows:

```
\def\strc_floats_prepare_page_caption
  {\edef\p_strc_floats_caption_width   {\floatcaptionparameter\c!width}%
   \edef\p_strc_floats_caption_minwidth{\floatcaptionparameter\c!minwidth}%
   \edef\p_strc_floats_caption_align   {\floatcaptionparameter\c!align}%
   \dostarttagged\t!floatcaption\empty
   \doifcommonelse\floatcaptionlocation{\v!top,\v!bottom,topframed,bottomframed}
      {\strc_floats_prepare_page_caption_top_bottom}
      {\ifx\p_strc_floats_caption_width\v!fit
         \strc_floats_prepare_side_auto_caption
       \else\ifx\p_strc_floats_caption_width\v!max
         \strc_floats_prepare_side_auto_caption
       \else
         \strc_floats_prepare_side_width_caption
      \fi\fi}%
   \dostoptagged}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}] 

\def\floatbackrule{\blackrule[width=\textwidth,height=.8pt,color=red]}

\unprotect
\installfloatboxbuilder {topframed}    \strc_floats_build_box_top_framed
\installfloatboxbuilder {bottomframed} \strc_floats_build_box_bottom_framed

\def\strc_floats_build_box_top_framed
    {\floatbackrule
     \strc_floats_build_box_top
     \floatbackrule}

\def\strc_floats_build_box_bottom_framed
    {\floatbackrule
     \strc_floats_build_box_bottom
     \floatbackrule}

\def\strc_floats_prepare_page_caption
  {\edef\p_strc_floats_caption_width   {\floatcaptionparameter\c!width}%
   \edef\p_strc_floats_caption_minwidth{\floatcaptionparameter\c!minwidth}%
   \edef\p_strc_floats_caption_align   {\floatcaptionparameter\c!align}%
   \dostarttagged\t!floatcaption\empty
   \doifcommonelse\floatcaptionlocation{\v!top,\v!bottom,topframed,bottomframed}
      {\strc_floats_prepare_page_caption_top_bottom}
      {\ifx\p_strc_floats_caption_width\v!fit
         \strc_floats_prepare_side_auto_caption
       \else\ifx\p_strc_floats_caption_width\v!max
         \strc_floats_prepare_side_auto_caption
       \else
         \strc_floats_prepare_side_width_caption
      \fi\fi}%
   \dostoptagged}

\protect


\setupcaption
  [
    location=topframed,
    align=flushleft,
    width=\textwidth,
  ]
\starttext 

\section{A figure with rules} 

\input knuth

\startplacefigure[title={\input zapf \relax}]
  \externalfigure[cow]
\stopplacefigure

\dorecurse{4}{\input knuth \endgraf}

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer comes close. It has a problem with longer captions, which don't wrap right. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Also the alignment parameter isn't regarded with `topframed` set: `\setupcaption[location=topframed,align=flushleft]`. With your core commands at hand I was digging into the ConTeXt source, but I haven't found a solution so far. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Another aspect: the `\floatbackrule` doesn't seem to be the problem. Even if you leave it out like this `\def\strc_floats_build_box_top_framed{\strc_floats_build_box_top}` the way the caption wraps change. Please try different caption lengths and widths for the figure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The next ConTeXt version will have the new command `\setupfloatframed` which can be used to set a background for the whole float block. The command takes the same arguments as `\setupframed` and the syntax for it is shown in the following image.

[image]

In addition to setting a background for the whole float you can also set individual backgrounds for the caption or the content of a float. To set the values for both elements you have to use the `\setupcaption` and `\setupfloat` commands which accept also the arguments of `\setupframed`.

```
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]

\setupcaption
  [figure]
  [location=top]

\setupfloatframed
  [figure]
  [width=max,
   toffset=1.5ex,
   boffset=1.5ex,
   framecolor=red,
   topframe=on,
   bottomframe=on]

\starttext

\samplefile{weisman}

\startplacefigure[title={A dutch cow}]
  \externalfigure[cow][width=6cm]
\stopplacefigure

\samplefile{weisman}

\setupfloat       [intermezzo] [background=color,backgroundcolor=red]
\setupcaption     [intermezzo] [background=color,backgroundcolor=blue]
\setupfloatframed [intermezzo] [background=color,backgroundcolor=green]

\startplaceintermezzo[title={Another cow}]
  \externalfigure[cow][width=6cm]
\stopplaceintermezzo

\samplefile{weisman}

\stoptext
```

[image]