# Context: How to do full-page figure with proper orientation and captions in opposite page?

Tags: floats, captions, context, layout

I've searched in ConTeXt manuals and here, but couldn't find a way to achieve these 4 requirements altogether:

1. Place a figure as full-page figure *(works without other requirements)*
2. Change orientation accordingly (if it's a landscape PDF, for instance)
3. Make that using `\setupfloat`(or other setup), not directly in `\placefloat`
4. Place captions in another page (ideally on opposite page)

Ideally, I would write something like

```
...

\definepapersize[rotate][A4, landscape]
\definelayout[expandrotate][topspace=0.5cm, topdistance=0cm, header=1cm, headerdistance=0cm,
                            height=20cm, footer=0cm, backspace=1.5cm, width=27.2cm]

\definefloat[bigfigure][bigfigures][figure]
\setupfloat[biglandscapefigure][default={page,none}, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight,
            before={\setuppapersize[rotate]\setuplayout[expandrotate]}] % setupfloat doesn't have 'before'

...

\startplacebiglandscapefigure[title={a little cat, taken from https://placekitten.com/}, reference=cat]
                    {\externalfigure[https://placekitten.com/200/300]}
\stopplacebiglandscapefigure
```

And achieve something like this (schematic example, made with Inkscape, out of scale):

[image: A short example: two pages, left with text column and floating caption, and right with full page image]

But with above code, I just get figure in separate *portrait* page, cropped by page boundaries (couldn't even figure out how to make caption in another page)... Also, I've searched in [reference](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf), [graphics](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/graphics.pdf) and [details](http://pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) manuals, without success...

### Related:

- [Figures/Floats and Section Headings on New Pages in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335078/figures-floats-and-section-headings-on-new-pages-in-context)
- [ConTeXt: Place rules above and below floating figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457412/context-place-rules-above-and-below-floating-figure)

Comment: Since you have received no reply here, it may be better to ask at the context mailing list

Comment: Thank you @Aditya, I'll try that.

Comment: For requirement # 2, as I'm using ConTeXt via Pandoc, I could write a Lua filter that wraps a command like `\setuplayout` around the figure. Now my main problem is requirement # 4...